# Load existing Excel file, change the zoom level for all sheets, and remove gridlines

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com

I'm using `win32com` to load an existing Excel doc. I'm currently able to loop through the sheets and remove text wrapping and autofit columns.

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False # I want to keep it this way


path = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\DDA"
wb_new = excel.Workbooks.Open(path + '\\new_file.xlsx')

# wb_new is a file with three tabs, with one value in cell A1 each... 
# ...if you want to recreate it.

active_sheets = wb_new.Sheets.Count
for i in range(0, active_sheets):
    ws = wb_new.Worksheets(i + 1)
    ws.Columns.WrapText = False
    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Next, I'd like to adjust the zoom level and remove gridlines for all sheets. I haven't found a solution that accomplishes this without making `excel.Visible = True`. I'm open to using a package from [python-excel.org](http://python-excel.org) but I haven't found anything.

I came across the `openpyxl.worksheet.views` subpackage which contains the `SheetView` class, but it doesn't seem to be useful for existing documents.

Comment: `AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.Zoom' can not be set` is the result of `ws.Zoom=75`

Comment: `AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.DisplayGridlines' can not be set.` is the result of `ws.DisplayGridlines=False`

Comment: Sorry, that property has to be set via a `Window` object, i.e. `excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom=75` and `excel.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines=False`.

Comment: That only works on the first sheet, the other two are not updated.

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to add `ws.Activate()`. Once I did this it worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False # I want to keep it this way


path = "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\DDA"
wb_new = excel.Workbooks.Open(path + '\\new_file.xlsx')

# wb_new is a file with three tabs, with one value in cell A1 each... 
# ...if you want to recreate it.

active_sheets = wb_new.Sheets.Count
for i in range(0, active_sheets):
    ws = wb_new.Worksheets(i + 1)
    ws.Columns.WrapText = False
    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
    ws.Activate() # answer starts here
    excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    excel.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
```